# Customize Tikz Circle Labels to Flow Along with the Circle Curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, circles

I want to label a circle I drew as a conglomeration of arcs and want it labeled on some `nodes` that will flow along the circle curves. What I currently have are `horizontal` labels, which do not flow along the circle curves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, xcolor}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:3.0) arc(90.0:67.5:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (45.0:3.0) arc(45.0:22.5:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (22.5:3.0) arc(22.5:00.0:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (00.0:3.0) arc(00.0:-22.5:3.0); 
        \draw[|-|] (-22.5:3.0) arc(-22.5:-45.0:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-45.0:3.0) arc(-45.0:-67.5:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-67.5:3.0) arc(-67.5:-90.0:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-90.0:3.0) arc(-90.0:-112.5:3.0); 
        \draw[|-|] (-112.5:3.0) arc(-112.5:-135.0:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-135.0:3.0) arc(-135.0:-157.5:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-157.5:3.0) arc(-157.5:-180.0:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-180.0:3.0) arc(-180.0:-202.5:3.0); 
        \draw[|-|] (-202.5:3.0) arc(-202.5:-225.0:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-225.0:3.0) arc(-225.0:-247.5:3.0);
        \draw[|-|] (-247.5:3.0) arc(-247.5:-270.0:3.0);
        \node at (90.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{n}$}};
        \node at (67.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_1$}};
        \node at (45.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_2$}};
        \node at (22.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$\cdots$}};
        \node at (00.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_l$}};
        \node at (-22.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{l+1}$}};
        \node at (-45.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{l+2}$}};
        \node at (-67.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$\cdots$}};
        \node at (-90.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{i}$}};
        \node at (-112.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{i+1}$}};
        \node at (-135.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{i+2}$}};
        \node at (-157.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$\cdots$}};
        \node at (-180.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{n-l}$}};
        \node at (-202.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$\cdots$}};
        \node at (-225.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{n-2}$}};
        \node at (-247.5:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{n-1}$}};
        %\foreach \i in {1,...,16} \node at ({112.5-22.5*\i}:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_{\i}$}};
        %\foreach \i in {17,...,21} \node at ({112.5-22.5*\i}:2.55) {\color{red}{$x_{\i}$}};
        %\node at (90.0:2.65) {\color{red}{$x_{n}$}};
        \node at (67.5:2.65) {\color{red}{$x_{n+1}$}};
        \node at (45.0:2.65) {\color{red}{$\cdots$}};
        \node at (22.5:2.65) {\color{red}{$x_{n+l-1}$}};
        \node at (00.0:2.65) {\color{red}{$x_{n+l}$}};
        %\node at (-22.5:2.65) {\color{red}{$x_{n+1-2}$}};
        %\node at (-45.0:2.65) {\color{red}{$x_{n+l-1}$}};
        %\node at (-67.5:2.65) {\color{red}{$x_{n+l}$}};
        
        %\draw[|-|] (157.5:2.4) arc(157.5:67.5:2.4) node[midway,fill=white]{$B_{n-3}$};
        \draw[|-|] (135:2.4) arc(135:45.0:2.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (112.5:2.0) arc(112.5:22.5:2.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:1.6) arc(90.0:00.0:1.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n}$};
        
        \draw[|-|] (90:4.0) arc(90:0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (60:4.4) arc(60:-30:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (30:4.8) arc(30:-60:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$};
        
        \draw[|-|] (180:4.8) arc(180:90:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l+1}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (210:4.4) arc(210:120:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (240:4.0) arc(240:150:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l-1}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**WHAT I WANT**

I want the `highlighted` parts to be labelled along the circle curves.

**NOTE**

I am a novices, I will prefer to have my code like this for now otherwise I will be confused with a more complicated ones. Therefore if you are providing an answer to this my question, simply add your code to mine and not remove my style for a complicated style that only advanced `text-nician` can understand.

Here is its [image: output presented]

Answer (score 6):

In case someone wants a more automatic approach.

I'm using the `ext.arrows` library of my `tikz-ext` package (> 0.5.1) to have a “Centered” Bar tip.

Using the `sloped` toggle we don't need to calculate any rotation at all when we're placing the `x_…` nodes along the arc.

You could actually do this already with your code if you place the nodes along the small arcs:

```
\draw[|-|, sloped, allow upside down] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0)
  node[at start, above, blue] {$\mathstrut x_1    $}
  node[at start, below, red]  {$\mathstrut x_{n+1}$};
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.arrows}% for Centered Bar
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[CB/.tip=Centered Bar]
\draw[sloped, allow upside down] (90-360/16:3cm)
  arc[start angle=90-360/16, delta angle=-360, radius=3cm]
  foreach[count=\i from 0] \BLUE/\RED in {
    x_1     / x_{n+1},
    x_2     / \dots,
    \dots   / x_{n+l-1},
    x_l     / x_{n+l},
    x_{l+1} / ,
    x_{l+2} / ,
    \dots   / ,
    x_i     / ,
    x_{i+1} / ,
    x_{i+2} / ,
    \dots   / ,
    x_{n-l} / ,
    \dots   / ,
    x_{n-2} / ,
    x_{n-1} / ,
    x_n     / 
  }{
    [nodes={pos=\i/16}]
    pic {arrow=CB}
    node[above, blue]{$\mathstrut\BLUE$}
    node[below, red] {$\mathstrut\RED$}
  } -- cycle;
\scoped[
  nodes={midway, fill=white},
  allow upside down, sloped, delta angle=-90, inner ysep=+0pt]
  \foreach \Radius/\deltaRadius/\LIST in {
    4cm  / .4cm/{ 90/1,      60  /2,    30/3},
    4cm  / .4cm/{240/n-l-1, 210  /n-l, 180/n-l+1},
    2.2cm/-.4cm/{135/n-2,   112.5/n-1,  90/n}}
    \foreach[count=\i from 0]\startAngle/\SUB in \LIST
      \draw[CB-CB] (\startAngle:\Radius+\deltaRadius*\i)
        arc[start angle=\startAngle, radius=\Radius+\deltaRadius*\i]
        node {$B_{\SUB}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In several answers, people suggested using `\foreach` (and I think that you should try to learn it; it's incredibly useful, and it's a basic structure for every programming language...). Using it you can do *one* change and not the tens of them you need here.

But if you insist on doing it one by one, just add the appropriate rotation to the node; for example, for *x_2*:

```
\node[rotate=-45] at (45.0:3.45) {\color{blue}{$x_2$}};
```

to have (I just changed this):

[image]

The amount of rotation could be calculated in a  formula with a `\foreach`, but if you do not like it, just change them by hand.

Comment: Maybe at least `\draw[|-|, sloped, allow upside down] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0) node[at start, above, blue]{$x_1$} node[at start, below, red]{$x_{n+1}$};` since `sloped` seems to be in OP's wheelhouse. (Throw in some struts for good measure.)

Answer (score 2):

You can place the nodes when you draw the arcs; you don't have to use the `\node` command on its own. Add `node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{<contents>}` to each arc for the blue nodes and `node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{<contents>}` for the red ones.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:3.0) arc(90.0:67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_1$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (67.5:3.0) arc(67.5:45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_2$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$\cdots$};
        \draw[|-|] (45.0:3.0) arc(45.0:22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l-1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (22.5:3.0) arc(22.5:00.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_l$}node[sloped, allow upside down, below=1mm, pos=1, red]{$x_{n+l}$};
        \draw[|-|] (00.0:3.0) arc(00.0:-22.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+1}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (-22.5:3.0) arc(-22.5:-45.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{l+2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-45.0:3.0) arc(-45.0:-67.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
        \draw[|-|] (-67.5:3.0) arc(-67.5:-90.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-90.0:3.0) arc(-90.0:-112.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+1}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (-112.5:3.0) arc(-112.5:-135.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{i+2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-135.0:3.0) arc(-135.0:-157.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$};
        \draw[|-|] (-157.5:3.0) arc(-157.5:-180.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-l}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-180.0:3.0) arc(-180.0:-202.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$\cdots$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (-202.5:3.0) arc(-202.5:-225.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-225.0:3.0) arc(-225.0:-247.5:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n-1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (-247.5:3.0) arc(-247.5:-270.0:3.0) node[sloped, allow upside down, above=1mm, pos=1, blue]{$x_{n}$};
        %%%
        \draw[|-|] (135:2.4) arc(135:45.0:2.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-2}$};
        \draw[|-|] (112.5:2.0) arc(112.5:22.5:2.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-1}$};
        \draw[|-|] (90.0:1.6) arc(90.0:00.0:1.6) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n}$};
        
        \draw[|-|] (90:4.0) arc(90:0:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_1$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (60:4.4) arc(60:-30:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_2$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (30:4.8) arc(30:-60:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_3$};
        
        \draw[|-|] (180:4.8) arc(180:90:4.8) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l+1}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (210:4.4) arc(210:120:4.4) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l}$}; 
        \draw[|-|] (240:4.0) arc(240:150:4.0) node[fill=white, midway, sloped, allow upside down, inner ysep=0pt]{$B_{n-l-1}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```